# Запуск batом jar файлов

Tags: java, bat, jar

согласно требованиям проект должен запускаться из консоли вводом
"compile.but && run.but". После сборки проекта имею один батник в папке проекта[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
ну а второй в следующей папке [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно сделать что-бы открыть сразу два файла вышеуказанным способом.(указание точного адреса, как понимаю, не очень подойдет, так как проект будет открываться не других устройствах и адрес меняется).Спасибо

Comment: А нельзя поместить еще 1 .bat, который открывает ваши 2 файла. Адреса будут, но они будут локальные(т.к. все в одной папке лежат) => он сможет запустить 2 файла по адресам.

Comment: Локальные - /файл.bat вроде как

Comment: @AntonSorokin можно, я думал даже просто в compile.bat добавить ссылку на run.bat и что-бы оно компайлом запускалось, но в условии отборочного задания написано что должно запускаться в таком виде compile.but && run.but

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, разобрался, все оказалось довольно просто - чтобы запустить run.bat вместе с compile.bat, достаточно рядом с compile.bat создать еще один bat, в котором прописать путь к нашему jar файлу в виде `java -jar target\Java-12-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. Спасибо всем, кто помогал.

Comment: Не забудьте через несколько дней принять свой ответ.

Answer (score 2):

В *NIX это можно сделать таким образом:
`<команда 1> & <команда 2>` (именно один амперсанд, а не два, для одновременного запуска).

Дело в том, что `&&` - это логический оператор И, и для проверки результата выполнения операндов он выполняет их поочерёдно, а не одновременно.